# DynamicResource throws an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have to apply the following style to my `ListViewItem`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

<local:Look x:Key="ListViewItemLook" Background="Magenta"/>


<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
<Style.Triggers>

    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={DynamicResource ListViewItemLook}, Path=Background}"/>
    </Trigger>

</Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

But i get an exception, i try to change:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background}"/>
```

And add to the Style:

```
<Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{DynamicResource ListViewItemLook}"/>
```

But is does not work. I can't bind to a StaticResource because I need to set the BackGround property run-time.

What have I to do? Thanks.

Comment: Is the Background property of Look class a Brush or Color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both local:Look and the setter to refer to the same color, perform a small refactor:

Pull the color out into a separate SolidColorBrush and make both items refer to it:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedListViewItemBackground" Color="Magenta" />
<local:Look x:Key="whatever" Background="{StaticResource SelectedListViewItemBackground}" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedListViewItemBackground}" />
```

If you're trying to do something else, I can't figure out what it is because the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: If the background is a StaticResource, when I change it (SelectedListViewItemBackground) at run-time, does my ListViewItem update its background automagically?

Comment: If you modify the color of the brush at runtime, no it doesn't. That's easy enough to change by making it a DynamicResource though. There's no change to the code beyond changing the word static into dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, DynamicResource extension uses the DependencyProperty mechanism (pretty much like a binding). Therefore you cannot set Source property of a Binding object with DynamicResource because it is not a DependencyProperty.

In addition, if you want to change the Background property of Look but not the Look itself in resources; then setting Look as a static resource to the binding property should not be a problem. Of course Background property of Look class should either trigger a PropertyChanged event or be a DependencyProperty itself.